# Peewee ORM gives IntegrityError: user_id may not be NULL

Tags: python, sqlite, orm, flask, peewee

I'm trying to use the Peewee ORM for my new (Flask) website, and now I ran into a problem. I just created a simple model like so:

```
from peewee import TextField, DateTimeField, IntegerField, ForeignKeyField
from app import db

ROLE_USER = 0
ROLE_ADMIN = 1

class User(db.Model):
    nickname = TextField()
    email = TextField()
    role = IntegerField(default = ROLE_USER)

class Post(db.Model):
    body = TextField()
    timestamp = DateTimeField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='posts')
```

So I created two users, after which I wanted to create a new post. I did this like so:

```
>>> from app.models import User
>>> u = User(nickname='john', email='john@email.com', role=0)
>>> u.save()
>>> from app.models import Post
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> p = Post(body='FIPO!!', timestamp = dt.now(), author=u)
>>> p.save()
No handlers could be found for logger "peewee"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2479, in save
    ret_pk = self.insert(**field_dict).execute()
  File "/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1775, in execute
    return self.database.last_insert_id(self._execute(), self.model_class)
  File "/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1470, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1885, in execute_sql
    return self.sql_error_handler(exc, sql, params, require_commit)
  File "/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/microblog/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1871, in sql_error_handler
    raise exception
sqlite3.IntegrityError: post.user_id may not be NULL
```

I don't understand that user_id apparently is NULL, because as far as I understand, peewee should take care of this right?

Am I doing something wrong (and if so; what?), or is this a problem with peewee? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're using `author=` when you should be using `user=`.

Original

```
p = Post(body='FIPO!!', timestamp = dt.now(), author=u)
```

Fixed

```
p = Post(body='FIPO!!', timestamp = dt.now(), user=u)
```